# Error while submitting Transaction through cardano-serialization-lib

Tags: nami-wallet, cardano-serialization-lib

I am trying to implement [Martify](https://github.com/OnChainLabs/Martify) contract using Cardano serialization lib. When I submit the transaction I get the following error. Can someone tell me what it mean?

`transaction submit error ShelleyTxValidationError ShelleyBasedEraAlonzo (ApplyTxError [UtxowFailure (WrappedShelleyEraFailure (UtxoFailure (UtxosFailure (ValidationTagMismatch (IsValid True) (FailedUnexpectedly [PlutusFailure \"\\nThe 3 arg plutus script (PlutusScript ScriptHash \\\"a306c90d19adfd7302e6d0a452aed3bd1d7f08e5b291d1add3d8e4fb\\\") fails.\\nCekError An error has occurred:  User error:\\nThe provided Plutus code called 'error'.\\nThe data is: Constr 0 [B \\\"\\\",I 100000000,B \\\"B\\\\DLEGO\\\\251\\\\142\\\\170Lpz6u\\\\155Tf\\\\223\\\\208\\\\173X]\\\\237\\\\143X\\154%\\169\\n\",B \"\"]\nThe redeemer is: Constr 0 []\nThe context is:\nPurpose: Spending (TxOutRef {txOutRefId = 0ba3`

Comment: I am  impressed since it appears that the shared repo is for submitting using cardano Cli! and Nami specs  don't match cardano-cli specs..but the error seems at a first look to be bassed on executing the plutus scripts... have you tried with this same transaction in the cli? to check if it is related to cardano serialization lib or to the contract perse?

Comment: I did try the same transaction through Cardano-cli which seems to be working perfectly fine. But when using Cardano-serialization-lib it keep on giving me this script failed eeror

Comment: ive read in Alessandro Twitter that Nami does not suport plutus contracts. But i am not sure why it is the case.. since is is a normal Tx  just with redemer and plutus scripts. so you took the plutus script, and used the cardano serialization lib to make the rest of the transaction?.. Maybe you should try to sign it using your prv keys in the library and send once int is signed.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same error. No idea what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: Lol I solved this issue. I was using a wrong tx id in my script utxo and the address in the datum was wrong too. Had to use `ownerAddress.payment_cred().to_keyhash()?.to_bytes()`.

Comment: @Displee Can you share your implementation with me? And how did you identify these errors, did you use any debugging technique or just hit and try .

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @DawarEjaz. Here's the full code: https://pastebin.com/DEzY3vCi

Comment: I met the same issue when the plutus script is 10 bytes long. Do you meet that issue, and can you repost your code example to solve that? Tks so much

Comment: @Displee Can you please share your code as an aswer to this question? Thank you!

Comment: Here is the full code: https://gist.github.com/Displee/63ca898e991e61786825c78764371444